# Winforms textbox override painting method

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to print a currency code at the end of the textbox without affecting the text value. I've been trying this code and that without any good result. Once I register the method to be painted by me, the system prints the text in the textbox with ugly bold font.

I tried to set it myself - no luck so far. The other thing when I type something with that ugly font, once I leave the textbox. The value disappears ....

I hope someone help me with this issue. I don't want headlights, I want to know what my problem is and how I can achieve what I want in a good way.

I have same thing and it works perfectly with datagrid cell value formatting. I managed to print the currency code without affecting the cell value.

When I enter the control, the code disappears and I get only the value. I leave the code reprinted with the cell value.

Any suggestions? I will appreciate it. This is in C#.

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox() 
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // Customize text rendering using TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor, flags);
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you combine regular `TextBox` (for money, which is editable) and regular `Label` for currency code (readonly)?

Comment: that's what I did now temporarily. but I hope to achieve it the way I want .. I appreciate ur suggestion mate.

Comment: Thats windows and it themes. When you do user painting you get original standard look because as you states you want to do the painting instead of window (so no more painting according to the current Windows Theme). So  typically when painting yourself you have to paint everything.

Comment: Ralf thanks for the positive comment, I totally agree that I have to do it myself. as I have seems examples I didn't find or figure out from where I can control the font family name and size etc.  I tried to change the text font style .. no vain actually .. I didn't the painting code in its place but there is a system intervention still there

Comment: Yes, you could fix this code to draw left and/or right labels by p/invoking to resize the internal editor area. Do you need that, or you just need to format the text to append/prepend currency symbol?

Comment: thanks for ur help dr.null.. I just want to draw the currency symbol at the end of the text when leaving the textbox .. that's all ..